# Large Replace formula for column with mixed letters and numbers for eventual sort and GIS import

Tags: excel

As a part of a large data conversion effort for eventual table joining, I'm creating a custom sort field in Excel to migrate into GIS but need to format a certain field in such a way the sort order will function according to the true sequence of sites. I’m using Excel 2010.  The data is for ~250,000 records (eventually millions of records).

```
Problem Field        How Excel Sorts It      The Needed Sort
585                  585                     585
979                  979                     585A
1175                 1175                    585B
1227A                1227A                   585C
585A                 585A                    979
585B                 585B                    979Q
585C                 585C                    979R
979Q                 797Q                    1175
979R                 979R                    1227A
B11                  B1                      B1
B1                   B11                     B9
B9                   B9                      B11
B90                  B90                     B90
```

Colleague and I decided to get around this issue by making a temporary site field that would do this.
Start with a letter (change corresponding first letter to a large number):

```
 B1  -->  20000001
 B11 -->  20000011
 G22 -->  70000022
```

And
End with a letter (change ending letter with a decimal to preserve sort order):

```
587A   -->  587.01
587M   -->  587.13
```

If it both starts with a letter and ends with a letter, keep the entire string as is.
I have two new fields, “StartsWithLetter” and “EndsWithLetter”, each with a True or False statement to show which fields have letters and where.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A4,{"a*","b*","c*","d*","e*","f*","g*","h*","i*","j*","k*","l*","m*","n*","o*","p*","q*","r*","s*","t*","u*","v*","w*","x*","y*","z*"}))>0
```

The entire field is then copy/pasted to show only the values of a string for TRUE or FALSE.

I’ve tried setting up more fields to do replacements, “CorrectLeft” and “CorrectRight” for eventual merging. I got the Right code to work correctly:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="A",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".01"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="B",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".02"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="C",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,".03"))))…etc.
```

But I’m having difficulty doing something similar for the Left side of the column.

Anyone have any ideas what’s going on with my code for the Left?

My code:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="A",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"100000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="B",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"200000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="C",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"300000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="D",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"400000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="E",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"500000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="F",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"600000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="G",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"700000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="H",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"800000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="I",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"900000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="J",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1000000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="K",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1100000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="L",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1200000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="M",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1300000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="N",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1400000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="O",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1500000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="P",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1600000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Q",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1700000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="R",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1800000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="S",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"1900000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="T",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2000000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="U",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2100000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="V",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2200000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="W",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2300000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="X",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2400000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Y",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2500000"),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Z",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"2600000")))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

If the “CorrectLeft” and “CorrectRight” fields work correctly I can build a formula like this to merge all the corrected fields if they have letters.

```
=IF(AND(B2="FALSE",C2="FALSE"),A2),IF(AND(B2="FALSE",C2="TRUE"),D2),IF(AND(B2="TRUE",C2="FALSE"),E2),IF(AND(B2="TRUE",C2="TRUE"),A2)
```

I have also tried combining several functions into a comprehensive formula, but figured it is best to get these separate formulas working before tinkering with efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If problem column is A, add a sort column:

```
// copy these cells down
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1,1)+0=LEFT(A1,1)+0,A1,"error"),CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1), TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"000000") ))
```

With this formula, value B1 becomes (in sort column) B000001, value B22 becomes B000022, value c65345 becomes c065345, etc.

If you need a longer set of minimum digits, change the "000000" in the formula to the number of digits you need.

Note that this only works if the second number is always a number, which seems to be the case with your dataset. The value AB23C, for example, would break this.

Comment: to handle up to 16 characters, sort column becomes: =IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1,1)+0=LEFT(A1,1)+0,A1,"error"),CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1), TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"0000000000000000") ))

Comment: Hi James, That's it! That's brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If problem field is in col A:

```
//copy this down   
=TEXT(A1,"###")
```

This will create another column that should sort as you wish.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the comment! I tried the formula you mentioned and resorted the data. It works for any site that ends with a letter, but still has issues for any site that starts with a letter. Example: It sorts as B19, B2, B20  rather than B2, B19, B20.

Comment: I just tested it in Excel successfully. Believe should work. Am I missing something? See MS's site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322067/how-to-correctly-sort-alphanumeric-data-in-excel

Comment: I read that article and tested out some sample data in fresh Excel workbook. The article shows examples that start with letters but I'm still getting incorrect sorts (i.e. "B1, B19, B2, B20, B21" rather than "B1, B2, B19, B20, B21"). I tried both sorting methods based on the radial options that appear when sorting. If sites that start with letters work for you; why would it not work for me? Edit: I also sorted based on the field with the formula and a copy/pasted field with just the values. Same issue.

Comment: @Matt See my new answer. Think it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it is ugly.

Break down the string into one character per cell with =IFERROR(VALUE(MID($A2, COLUMNS($A$2:A$2), 1)),""). You just drag this to the right of the value for the max length of the longest value. So 16 characters = 16 cells required.

Next, to the right of this, =ISERR(VALUE(LEFT(A2,1)))
Next, to the right of this, =ISERR(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1)))

Lastly, to the right of this, =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(IF(ISERR(VALUE(LEFT(A2,1))),LEFT(A2,1),""),10000+CONCATENATE(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2)),IF(ISERR(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1))),RIGHT(A2,1),""))

10000 needs to be one more 0 than the max count of digits in your data set. Your example is 4 digits, so 10,000 was used. If the max count is 16, then it would be 10,000,000,000,000,000.

The inner concatenate also needs to be modified to add every column that you used for the first formula. This example used 6, if the max length is 16, then add 10 more columns, e.g. (H2, I2,...).

Then if you sort this result, excel will have a popup and choose the 2nd option, sort and treat numbers and text separately.

Comment: Hi Nicho, in this particular dataset the max length is 8. Some sites I think can go to 16.